# Failure in installing python packages pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5
python: python2.7.17
I created a python script in python 2.7.17

I have 20+ production servers all running at different versions of python2.7, say python 2.7.6, python 2.7.13

When I am installing the requirements.txt using virtualenv created with python2.7.13, everything is working fine.
However, when I install packages on servers with python2.7.6, I get an error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cachetools==3.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cachetools==3.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

The problem is the version of packages in requirements.txt doesn't exist for python2.7.6 (python2.7.6 may have the package at a lower version)

How do I fix this version mismatch?

Is there any way to auto-detect the latest version of the package basis on the python version and then install it?

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the pip docs [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#), that

> Once pip has the set of requirements to satisfy, it chooses which version of each requirement to install using the simple rule that the latest version that satisfies the given constraints will be installed.

So, I suggest removing the package version specifier, for example replace `pip install cachetools==3.1.1` with `pip install cachetools`.